# $n^n$ are the moments of a measure on the non-negative real line?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions

I would like to know if the numbers $1,1,2^2,3^3,\dots, n^n,\dots$ are the moments with respect some measure $\mu$ on $[0,+\infty)$, i.e., if there exists such a measure $\mu$ with
$$n^n=\int_0^\infty t^n d\mu(t) \quad n=0,1,2,\dots$$

Comment: If the answer is yes, since $n^n$ and $n!$ are quite alike, I think it should be somehow something similar to the function gamma because it holds
$$n!=\int_0^\infty t^n\,e^{-t} dt.$$

Comment: You may be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_moment_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This $\mu$ is a probability distribution  on $[0,\infty)$ (from the case $n=0$).  Let $X$ be a random variable with that distribution.  Then $n^n$ are the moments of $X$, and the moment generating function of $X$ is
$$
\mathbb E[e^{tX}] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^n}{n!}\;t^n = \frac{1}{1+W(-t)}
$$
where $W$ is the Lambert W function.  So our measure is the inverse Laplace transform of this function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Some information like this is what I was looking for... Hence I understand (from your answer) that there are no problems with this Lambert function ( more precisely with 1/(1+W) ) in order to apply the inverse Laplace transform... Right? On the other hand, is it known? (I mean, does it has a precise expression?) Could you please suggest me some bibliography for all this? I would appreciate it so much!!

Comment: I am interested in completely justifying why "everything works" regarding this Lambert function and the suitable inverse Laplace transform... I need it for a work. I would really appreciate your help (although it is only by means of that you provide me some bibliography). Thanks in advance!